# Android Eclipse & Android Studio App Release signed

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, google-play

I have a app which I released many years ago on the market. It was originally done in Eclipse. Now i am making a new version of the app in Android studio. I still have the original key and password it was signed with.

Can i update the already published app made in eclipse with the new one im making in Android studio, as long as i use the same key it was signed with?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work. Are you just asking here *before* you do something wrong?

Comment: As long as you know the password for the key, one could care less what you use to compile the code.

Comment: Same package name and same signing key - no problem at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answers as I didnt want to make the new app in Android studio and then find out I couldnt update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i update the already published app made in eclipse with the new
>   one I'm making in Android studio, as long as i use the same key it was
>   signed with?

**Yes, you can.**

Refer the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/studio/eclipse-transition-guide.html#signing).

> If your app used a debug certificate in Eclipse ADT, Android Studio
>   continues to reference that certificate. Otherwise, the debug
>   configuration uses the Android Studio generated debug keystore, with a
>   known password and a default key with a known password located in
>   $HOME/.android/debug.keystore. The debug build type is set to use this
>   debug SigningConfig automatically when you run or debug your project
>   from Android Studio.
>
> In release mode, Android Studio applies the release certificate used
>   in Eclipse ADT. If no release certificate was located during the
>   import process, add the release signing configuration to the
>   build.gradle file or use the Build > Generate Signed APK menu option
>   to open the Generate Signed APK Wizard. For more information about
>   signing your app, see Signing Your Applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you need to use the same key and the same package name.